# How do i get the response from prompt

Tags: javascript, html

How do i get the response from a prompt window and make it show up somewhere on the webpage?

The code i have right now is:

```html
<html>

<head>

 <center>

  <FORM> 

   <INPUT type="button" value="Click Me." name="button" onClick="alert('I Like Waffles')">

   <INPUT type="button" value="Whats Your Favorite Food" name="button" onClick="prompt('Whats Your Favorite Food?')">

  </FORM>

 </center>

</head>

</html>
```

i want to know how to take the response from the prompt and place it somewhere in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example:

```
<html>

<head>

<center>
    <script>
    function gen(){
        var a = prompt("What's your favorite food?");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    }
    </script>

    <FORM> 

        <INPUT type="button" value="Click Me." name="button" id="button" onClick="alert('I Like Waffles')">

        <INPUT type="button" value="Whats Your Favorite Food" name="button" onClick="gen();">
        <p id="demo"></p>

    </FORM>

</center>
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/856k6j0d/)

Comment: how would i make it so when it returns it, it adds a text with it like, the return is waffles for example and i want it to print "waffles, are awesome"

Answer (score 1):

Prompt will return the value.

```
 alert(prompt('Whats Your Favorite Food?'))
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 <center>

  <FORM> 

   <INPUT type="button" value="Click Me." name="button" onClick="alert('I Like Waffles')">

   <INPUT type="button" value="Whats Your Favorite Food" name="button" onClick="alert(prompt('Whats Your Favorite Food?'))">

  </FORM>

 </center>

</head>

</html>
```